# How to post this JSON data as HTTP body using URLSession?

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

The JSON I have to post:

```
{
  "quizId": 1,
  "quizQuestionBanks": [
    {
      "quizQuestionBankId": 4,
      "question": "string",
      "option1": "string",
      "option2": "string",
      "option3": "string",
      "option4": "string",
      "answer": "Guy de Maupassant",
      "explanation": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I did the URLSession Post part. But don't know how to post this kind of JSON. Earlier I have posted JSON like this.

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["key": "value"]
```

But it's a bit complex for me.

The code I did for posting is given below

```
let url = URL(string: postUrl)! //PUT Your URL

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.addValue("Token \(String(describing: token))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        // insert json data to the request
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON) //Code after Successfull POST Request
            }
        }.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `JSONSerialization`:

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["quizId": 1,
                             "quizQuestionBanks": [["quizQuestionBankId": 4,
                                                    "question": "string",
                                                    "option1": "string",
                                                    "option2": "string",
                                                    "option3": "string",
                                                    "option4": "string",
                                                    "answer": "Guy de Maupassant",
                                                    "explanation": "string"]]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
```

But, since Swift 4, we can use Codable:

```
struct Quiz: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let questions: [Question]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "quizId"
        case questions = "quizQuestionBanks"
    }
}

struct Question: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let question: String
    let option1: String
    let option2: String
    let option3: String
    let option4: String
    let answer: String
    let explanation: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "quizQuestionBankId"
        case question
        case option1
        case option2
        case option3
        case option4
        case answer
        case explanation
    }
}

let questions = [Question(id: 4, question: "string", option1: "string", option2: "string", option3: "string", option4: "string", answer: "Guy de Maupassant", explanation: "string")]
let quiz = Quiz(id: 1, questions: questions)
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(quiz)
```

`option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4`, could be an array in struct (that would need a custom encoding/decoding).

Comment: How to initialize quiz variable as empty for this line below: 

var quiz = Quiz(quizId: 1, quizQuestionBanks: [QuizQuestionBank(quizQuestionBankId: 4, question: "string", option1: "string", option2: "string", option3: "string", option4: "string", answer: "Guy de Maupassant", explanation: "string")])

Answer (score 3):

**Prepare JSON data for upload**

```
 struct Quiz: Codable {
        let quizId: Int
        let quizQuestionBanks: [QuizQuestionBank]
    }

struct QuizQuestionBank: Codable {
    let quizQuestionBankId: Int
    let question: String
    let option1: String
    let option2: String
    let option3: String
    let option4: String
    let answer: String
    let explanation: String

}

let quiz = Quiz(quizId: 1, quizQuestionBanks: [QuizQuestionBank(quizQuestionBankId: 4, question: "string", option1: "string", option2: "string", option3: "string", option4: "string", answer: "Guy de Maupassant", explanation: "string")])

guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(quiz) else {
    return
}
```

**Configure URL request**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/post")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

**Use upload task**

```
let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print ("error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
            print ("server error")
            return
        }
        if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
            mimeType == "application/json",
            let data = data,
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print ("got data: \(dataString)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

See this link from **Apple developer site** for more detailed information.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/uploading_data_to_a_website

Comment: Thanks. 
I think the line will be: 
guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(quiz) else {
            return
        }

Comment: How to initialize quiz variable as empty for this line below: 

var quiz = Quiz(quizId: 1, quizQuestionBanks: [QuizQuestionBank(quizQuestionBankId: 4, question: "string", option1: "string", option2: "string", option3: "string", option4: "string", answer: "Guy de Maupassant", explanation: "string")])

Comment: Declare it as optional " var quiz: Quiz? " and initialize when you get the value " quiz =  Quiz(quizId: 1, quizQuestionBanks: [QuizQuestionBank(quizQuestionBankId: 4, question: "string", option1: "string", option2: "string", option3: "string", option4: "string", answer: "Guy de Maupassant", explanation: "string")]) "

Comment: Oh My God! You are awesome! :D